# Installing Mono 3.4.0 and MonoDevelop 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

### I went through some problems installing the latest versions of mono and monodevelop. After solving the problems I decided to post for those who need it someday.

> The process below worked perfectly on my lap top Alienware MX11R3

### 1-)Download Mono Run time

```
http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.4.0.tar.bz2
```

### 2-)Extract tarballs

```
tar -xjvf mono-3.4.0.tar.bz2
```

### 3-)Install It

```
cd mono-3.4.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

### 4-)Install MonoDevelop Deps

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2.0-cil-dev 
sudo apt-get install gnome-sharp2
```

### 5-)Put libs in Gac

```
cd /usr/lib/cli

sudo gacutil -i glib-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i atk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gdk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i glade-sharp-2.0/glade-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i pango-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-sharp-2.24/gnome-sharp.dll && 
sudo gacutil -i gconf-sharp-2.0/gconf-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-vfs-sharp-2.0/gnome-vfs-sharp.dll
```

### 6-)Download MonoDevelop

```
http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/monodevelop-4.2.2-2.tar.bz2
```

### 7-)Extract tarballs

```
tar -xjvf monodevelop-4.2.2-2.tar.bz2
```

### 8-)Install It

```
cd monodevelop-4.2.2
./configure --prefix=`pkg-config --variable=prefix mono`
make
sudo make install
```

Enjoy.

ps: Sorry, i was pretending answer a question, but after registration account,  i lost the question and post this, changing the format to be more usefull. If this post is so bad and nothing usefully, please tell me and i will delete then

Comment: What is your question? SO is not a blog nor forum. No to mention your "question" is off topic

Comment: Register a free blog and then post it. I agree SO is not the place for such posts. Besides, such steps can easily break as the 3.4.0 branch is still active (last updated on May 15, https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/mono-3.4.0-branch).

Comment: @PauloAmf, it's useful, but it doesn't fit the SO format. What you should (and still can) do is to edit the question to look like "How to to install Mono 4.4.0 ... ?".  Then post your own answer with this information. It's perfectly OK to answer your own questions on SO, there's even a tick box for this when you ask a question.

Comment: I get this error configure: error: Can't find "gmcs" in your PATH... Any suggestion? :)

Comment: Found better instructions at http://www.rocko.me/install-mono-3-4-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

Try this ppa for Mono 4.x https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/monodevelop-latest

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest

apt-get update

apt-get install mono-complete
```